# Как организовать хранение прогресса выполнения задачи?

Tags: reactjs, разработка-игр, redux

Делаю некую игру и там нужно выполнить последовательность действий. Например войти —> сесть за стол—> выйти.
Причем между этими действиями могут быть еще любые, но неверные. То есть цепочка эта может идти не подряд, но все равно считаться верной, если эти действия выполнены в таком порядке ,то пользователь переходить к следующему шагу. Потом снова ему нужно выполнить некие действия и т.д.
Помогите с алгоритмом и что хранить в сторе.

то есть такие действия например тоже приведут юзера к следующему шагу
войти —> неверное действие -> сесть за стол—> неверное действие -> выйти

Answer (score 1):

Судя по описанию, достаточно хранить состояние выполнения задачи.

Действия - переходы между состояниями, в данном случае (плохое действие не сбрасывает в ноль) конечный автомат (машина состояний) линейный

```
войти: если состояние < 2, то состояние 1
сесть за стол: если состояние 1, то состояние 2
выйти: если состояние 2, то состояние 3 => выполнено
```

Во-первых, хранится число (или перечислимый тип) - состояние, state. Нужно нарисовать конечный автомат. Он будет выглядеть как цепочка 1 - 2 - 3 и петли на 1 и 2. Действия (action) вызывают переходы (transition) в зависимости от текущего состояния. Во-вторых, хранится таблица переходов как двумерный массив или список списков.

Comment: а как сам стор примерно будет выглядеть?  можно чуть поподробнее. пока непонятно(
то есть мне надо выполнить некие действия чтобы перейти к следующей локации. если действие неверно, то выводим неки ответ.и ждем когда юзер выполнит следующее действие и т.д. Если юзер выполняет эту цепочку,то success